# How add first two character in Textdrawable library?

Tags: java, android, github, android-library

Hello friend I am using     `compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1' this library in my project i want add first two character in`TextDrawable`icon if anyone know about this library please help how add first two character of my text in`TextDrawable`icon here is my code my it show only first character of my`TextView`in`TextDrawable` icon but I want it show first two character please help me?

```
//get first letter of each String item
String firstLetter = String.valueOf(getItem(position).charAt(0));

ColorGenerator generator = ColorGenerator.MATERIAL; // or use DEFAULT
// generate random color
int color = generator.getColor(getItem(position));

TextDrawable drawable = TextDrawable.builder().buildRound(firstLetter,//radius in px color);
```

My xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:paddingLeft="20sp"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textColor="@color/darkcolor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="John" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Dinesh Shingadiya  please tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use substring() instead of chaAt()

```
String firstTwoChars = getItem(position).subString(0,2);
```

Comment: it's may be width issue . can you increase width as what specified in github?

Comment: oh may be wait?

Comment: try scaletype `center_inside

Comment: add `android:scaleType="centerInside"` to your image view and try

Comment: stil using String.valueOf(getItem(position).charAt(0))?

Comment: no i am using this code          String firstLetter = String.valueOf(getItem(position).substring(0,1));

Comment: please check this library and tell me

Comment: @user10968638 I have updated answer , kindly check it

Comment: Rajasekaran M i already solved my problem same code thanks helping me